# Struts2 global result throwing StackOverflowError on result type chain/tiles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

below are my interceptors & global-results as defined in struts.xml

```
 <package name="auth_basic" extends="struts-default,tiles-default">
<interceptors>
        <interceptor name="nlogin" class="interceptors.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
    <global-results>
        <result name="login" type="redirectAction">gotostart</result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">gotostart</result>
    </global-results>
.
.
.
</package>
```

The above configuration works fine, but when I use result `chain` instead of `redirectAction` it gives java.lang.StackOverflowError

Also when I use `tiles` instead of chain, then also it throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Can I not use action-chaining in global-results ?

Below is my interceptor code. Also, I would like to EMPHASIZE on the point that result type redirectAction is working fine, only tiles & chain are creating problems.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (ai.getInvocationContext().getSession().get("user") == null) {
            System.out.println("Session Expired/Invalid");
            Object action = ai.getAction();
            if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
                ((ValidationAware) action).addActionError("Unauthorized access. Please Login first");
            }
            return "login";
        }
        return ai.invoke();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ai.invoke();
}
```

`edited to include more code from struts.xml`

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default,tiles-default,json-default">
    <default-action-ref name="gotostart"/>
    <global-results>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">tiles-home</result>
    </global-results>
<action name="gotostart" class="actions.IndexAction" method="start">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles-home</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">tiles-home</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong in your `nLogin` interceptor. stackOverflowError means 99% of the times that you are in an endless loop; try debugging it, and you will see...

Comment: @AndreaLigios I've edited the question to contain my interceptor code. Please note that redirectAction result type ain't giving errors only chain & tiles result-types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it.

If not logged in, you are returning an global result, `login`, that is a `chain` result type, then a call to another action.

The `login` result type is under the same Interceptor Stack containing the `nLogin Interceptor`.

This means that when you try to chain your `login` result, you pass AGAIN inside your `nLogin Interceptor`, checking again if `user` is null, and returning `login` result, in and endless loop.

You can:

return a JSP instead of chaining to another Action, like this:

```
<result name="login">myLogin.jsp</result>
```

or move your global result `login` outside your custom Interceptor Stack scope (putting it under the default stack in a parent package, for example), like this:

```
<struts>
   <package name="defaultPackage" extends="struts-default" >

      <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

      <global-results>
         <result name="login" type="chain">
            <param name="actionName">myLoginAction</param>
         </result>
      </global-results>

   </package>

   <package name="myLoginProtectedPackage" extends="defaultPackage">

      <interceptors>
         <interceptor name="nlogin" class="interceptors.LoginInterceptor"/>
         <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
         </interceptor-stack>
      </interceptors>

      <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>

      <global-results>
        <result name="input" type="chain">
            <param name="actionName">myLoginAction</param>
        </result>
      </global-results>    

      <action name="myLoginAction" class="...">
         <result>myLogin.jsp</result>             
      </action>

   </package>
</struts>
```

Don't ask me why with redirectAction works... it should be the same, but probably is due to their different behavior.

Please note that, [according to the guide](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/action-chaining.html),

> As a rule, Action Chaining is not recommended. First explore other options, such as the Redirect After Post technique.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. But chained action (gotostart) has the defaultInterceptorStack and hence it won't return "login" result again.

Comment: Then, this is not what you posted. In what you posted, the global-result is under the "loginStack". Are you sure ? Can you post the complete struts.xml (with chains, if the problem is in chains, not with redirectActions) ?

Comment: right global result is under the LoginStack, but the chained action has a different interceptor stack. I've edited the question to have more details. Please see.

Comment: This means that when you try to chain from Login result to GotoStart Action, it will pass through the loginStack, as i said :| The stack is traversed before reaching the Action, not after... try moving the login result from global of auth-package to global of default-package, and watch the result...

Comment: ok, seems like I'm getting it. Interceptors will also be called after the result. right ? Although moving the login result out of auth package makes no sense, since actions within that package needs to be authenticated, so I can't have a result from other package to be returned by actions of some other package. Although I seem to get the whole point, on why chaining is not working. If you write up an answer explaining my fault, I'll be glad to accept.